# How to return new class instance from generic method based on given types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have two parent classes: `Item` and `ItemData`. From the first, I make items such as `WeaponItem` and from the second I make corresponding data like `WeaponData`.
Each item type takes the same type of data in its constructor (example: when creating `WeaponItem` it needs `WeaponData`).

I have the following method:

```
public static T CreateNewItem<T, DT>(ItemData data) where T : Item where DT : ItemData
{
    if (data == null) return null;
    if (data is DT dt)
    {
        //determine type of T
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        if (itemType = typeof(WeaponItem))
        {
                //make a new weapon item...
                WeaponItem new_weapon = new WeaponItem(dt); //error!
                return new_weapon;
        }
        if (itemType = typeof(ArmorItem))
        {
                //make a new armor item...
        }
        //etc...
    }
    return null;
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
CreateNewItem<WeaponItem, WeaponData>(data);
```

Note: `data` is of type `ItemData` or some inherited type (eg. `WeaponData`).

This method needs two types: one for the `Item` and one for the `ItemData`. I have several items (weapons, armors etc...) and I create the item based on the type I give. I want to also check for the data which I do with: `data is DT dt` to get the `WeaponData` from the data I pass, or `null` if the cast fails.

When I try doing `WeaponItem new_weapon = new WeaponItem(dt);` I get the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DT' to 'WeaponData' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1503)

I tried casting `dt` to `WeaponData` like so: `WeaponItem new_weapon = new WeaponItem((WeaponData)dt);` , but I get a similar error

> Cannot convert type 'DT' to 'WeaponData' [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0030)

Similarly, using `data` in place of `dt` produces errors.

---

Is it possible to solve this problem without checking the type every time?

Comment: What, precisely, is the point of this method, as opposed to calling `new WeaponItem(data)` directly? This is important because, depending on where you get the types from, there may be easier ways than making a generic method do this -- that doesn't add much of anything in the way of being "generic" or type safe the way it's used here.

Comment: I sort through several stuff before I call this method to make sure I have the right combination of types: `Item` and `ItemData`. I am trying to avoid having to write extensive `if/else` cases for each item and data combination with this method.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I agree. It's bad practice to check if a thing is a certain type and based on that to do another thing, op breaks the open closed principle of SOLID. Better to just pass the data needed for the item in it's constructor as you pointed out.

Comment: You could make `Item` responsible for either producing `ItemData`, and/or just verifying the type (i.e. `Item { protected Item(ItemData data) }; WeaponItem { public WeaponItem(WeaponData data) : base(data)` or `public WeaponItem(ItemData data) : base(data) { if (data is not WeaponData) throw... }` . This coupling would be benign, as opposed to centralizing everything (though if you do want to centralize things or make them more dynamic, other patterns work there, like `Dictionary`s and `Func`s).

Comment: @Lae create item classes (sword,shield,potion e.t.c). For each of them, pass the correct data class the item needs. For sword and other type of swords you may create in the future you will pass SwordData, for shields and other shields you pass ShieldData. When the time comes to have a special sword that has all abilities of the normal sword, but additional power up abilities as well, you can easily create a class PowerSword that inherits from Sword and accepts a SwordData/ PowerSwordData that inherits from SwordData.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is how my `Item` and `WeaponItem` classes are setup. I have considered using a `Dictionary<Type, int>` or something similar to check for types faster, as you point out.

Comment: @NikolaDevelops This is exactly my problem! To make the classes, the correct data needs to be passed first. I have edited the introduction to my question, I hope now the way I've set my code up is easier to understand.

Comment: The object would not be to check for types "faster" but to reduce duplication and tight coupling (like you get if all classes have to be mentioned in one method, giving multiple places that have to be changed if you add or remove an item). Performance should only be a distant goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is a bit counter intuitive to me, so let's start with an extremely simple version of the generic method and go from there.  This code you can copy and compile.

You can also click [this link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZwAut) and just hit the Run button.

I'd say the biggest advantage here is the generic method became one line of code. You can add as many items as you want and never change that method.  Whereas your implementation gets more and more complex.

Code:

```
public class ItemData
{
    public string ItemName { get; init; }
}

public class WeaponData : ItemData { }

public class Item
{
    public ItemData Data { get; init; }

    public Item(ItemData data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}

public class WeaponItem : Item  
{
    public WeaponItem(WeaponData data) : base(data) { }

    public override string ToString() => Data.ItemName;
}

public static T CreateNewItem<T, TD>(TD data) 
    where T : Item 
    where TD : ItemData
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), data);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bestWeaponDataEver = new WeaponData() { ItemName = "Dragon Slayer" };
    var amazingWeapon = CreateNewItem<WeaponItem, WeaponData>(bestWeaponDataEver);
    Console.WriteLine(amazingWeapon);
}
```

Output:

> Dragon Slayer

Another big difference is you're accepting the specific type `ItemData` which should be the generic type `DT`.  Otherwise why does  `DT` even exist?  This might have tripped you up.

```
public static T CreateNewItem<T, DT>(ItemData data) where T : Item where DT : ItemData
```

Should be this instead

```
public static T CreateNewItem<T, DT>(DT data) where T : Item where DT : ItemData
```

Note the constructor for `WeaponItem` only accepts `WeaponData`. So despite the simple generic method, you can't create a weapon with the base `ItemData` or `CakeData` or anything else.

If you're not sure how to expand on this comment and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Thank you for the easy to understand example. Even though I changed by code by the time you posted the answer, in an older version `(T)Activator.CreateInstance()` seems to be the code I was missing. And the change from `ItemData` to `DT` in the method parameters change seems logical now.
I don't understand what you mean by "signature". Could you be a little more detailed in what I am doing wrong so I can understand it?
Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lee My apologies, I meant "method signature".  Basically you create a generic type `DT` with type constraints, but don't enforce it.  This would compile `public static T CreateNewItem<T, DT>(int data) where T : Item where DT : ItemData` if you swapped that in your original code.  And I don't think you want that.

Comment: I see, it makes sense to enforce the constraint. One last thing: is it considered *good practice* to initialize from generics using the `Activator.CreateInstance` or would it be wiser to change my code and instance in a more "traditional" way?

Comment: @Lae `Activator.CreateInstance` is exactly what is called when you construct a generic type.  Say you put a `new` constraint on type `T` and wrote `var item = new T()`.  The compiler swaps that out with `Activator.CreateInstance`, literally.  Same thing.  We call it explicitly here because you're passing a parameter.